# Remove label from scrollview

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uiscrollview, uilabel

I am creating an iPhone app in which i am using scrollview and adding labels like this :

```
question = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22, 130, 725, 160)] ;
question.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,selected];
question.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
[question setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:30]];
question.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
question.numberOfLines = 0;
[question sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:question];
[scrollview addSubview:question];
```

now i want to remove this label from scrollview. So how can i do this..??
i am doing this for remove object from main view.

```
 [question removeFromSuperview];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you adding `question` to the main view and to the scroll view? It doesn't make sense. Remove the `[self.view addSubview:question];` line and `[question removeFromSuperview];` will remove your label from the scrollview.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your code. I assume that the scrollview is a subview of `self.view`. In this case remove the line

```
[self.view addSubview: question];
```

from you code. Depending on the rest of your code I would eventually also change the first line. If you don't need to excess the label somewhere else in your code I would change the first line to

```
UILabel *question = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(22, 130, 725, 160)];
```

and add a line after `[scrollview addSubview: question];` with

```
[question release];
```

This would reduce you memory consumption.

Comment: Thans dasdom..
I have declared my label in .h file with (retain , nonatomic) property.. and ya, i forgot to release it :P.. Thanks :)